# how to run 3 different exe files when the appropriate button is clicked in C++ Visual studio

Tags: c++

I have a windows form application and I have 3 different buttons. When I click each of them I want it to run different exe files. I searched on the web but have not found any help. 
These exe files that i wan tto run are some opengl things that i built.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Have you tried [`ShellExecute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

Comment: *"These exe files that i wan tto run are some opengl things that i built"* - if you have source files of these, you might consider turning them into some kind of libraries or COM objects that your fronted will use...

Comment: Thanks guys! LihO i tried your suggestion and it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your question, then what you need is to create a process. This can be achieved by using the [`CreateProcess()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method that C++ offers.

```
BOOL WINAPI CreateProcess(
  _In_opt_     LPCTSTR lpApplicationName,
  _Inout_opt_  LPTSTR lpCommandLine,
  _In_opt_     LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpProcessAttributes,
  _In_opt_     LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes,
  _In_         BOOL bInheritHandles,
  _In_         DWORD dwCreationFlags,
  _In_opt_     LPVOID lpEnvironment,
  _In_opt_     LPCTSTR lpCurrentDirectory,
  _In_         LPSTARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo,
  _Out_        LPPROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation
);
```

Below is an [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) taken from MSDN:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

void _tmain( int argc, TCHAR *argv[] )
{
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );

    if( argc != 2 )
    {
        printf("Usage: %s [cmdline]\n", argv[0]);
        return;
    }

    // Start the child process. 
    if( !CreateProcess( NULL,   // No module name (use command line)
        argv[1],        // Command line
        NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
        NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
        FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
        0,              // No creation flags
        NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
        NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
        &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
        &pi )           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
    ) 
    {
        printf( "CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError() );
        return;
    }

    // Wait until child process exits.
    WaitForSingleObject( pi.hProcess, INFINITE );

    // Close process and thread handles. 
    CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );
    CloseHandle( pi.hThread );
}
```

Comment: don't forget to up-vote my answer if you consider it'